# How can I create a filtered unique index in mysql? It's possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, indexing

I need to create a filtered index on a MySQL database table.

The index that I want to create must be unique for columns X and Z when Z is not NULL.

I have knowledge of how to create it in SQLServer, as follows:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IndexName
     ON TableName(ColumnX, ColumnZ)
     WHERE ColumnZ IS NOT NULL ;
```

I have tried this in MySQL:

```
CREATE INDEX demo_idx
ON camp_cdr (call_id,ans_time) 
WHERE ans_time is not null;
```

But I get a syntax error. I have searched various forums and documentation but have not found.

Any how to do it?

Comment: MySQL does not support filtered indexes, but it might do what you want already. In MySQL (and the SQL standard), unique indexes already allow multiple NULLs. Microsoft only allows one row with a NULL in a unique index, which is non-standard. Have you tried just creating a unique index and inserting some rows with NULLs and with non-NULLs, and see if it works how you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The index that I want to create must be unique for columns X and Z when Z is not NULL.

If you'd create unique index by `(X,Z)` then all rows which contains NULL in at least one of the mentioned columns will be treated as unique and hence will be allowed even when the value in another column is dupicated.

```
CREATE TABLE test ( x INT, z INT, UNIQUE (x,z) );
```

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2);
```

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,1);  -- not allowed
```

> ```
> Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'test.x'
> ```

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,NULL),(1,NULL),(NULL,2),(NULL,2);  -- allowed
```

```
TABLE test;
```

| x | z |
| --- | --- |
| *null* | 2 |
| *null* | 2 |
| 1 | *null* |
| 1 | *null* |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ol6mAeEM)